# Как выбрать уникальные записи по условию?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, bigquery

Есть таблица, вот пример:

```
email   carrier id  date
email_1 car_1   1   2019-02-08
email_1 car_1   1   2019-02-09
email_1 car_1   2   2019-02-10
email_1 car_2   2   2019-02-11
email_2 car_3   3   2019-02-09
email_2 car_4   4   2019-02-09
```

С этой таблице мне нужну выбрать уникальные записи. 
Критерием уникальности будет следующее: 
Если внутри одного `email`-а, значение в поле `carrier` уникальное и значение в поле `id` уникальное, то такая запись будет уникальной. Значение поле `date` не должно влиять на уникальность записи. Можем выводить первую при сортировке по дате уникальную запись по дате.
Результат должен быть вот такой:

```
email   carrier id  date
email_1 car_1   1   2019-02-08
email_1 car_2   2   2019-02-11
email_2 car_3   3   2019-02-09
email_2 car_4   4   2019-02-09
```

`DISTINCT` не подойдет, так как при его использовании, любое изменение в колонке есть критерием уникальности записи.
Как сделать такой запрос? 
Запрос буду выполнять в `BigQuery`, но подойдет и пример на `SQL` :)
Спасибо

Comment: Почему из итогового результата выпала запись `('email_1', 'car_1', 2, '2019-02-10')`?

Comment: потому что car_1 уже есть в предыдущих записях с email_1. Посмотрите внимательно описание задачи:) Там есть критерии отбора )

Comment: Тогда вы неверно формулируете критерии. Получается, что для пары (email, carrier) надо выбрать запись с минимальной датой. А уж какой у неё id получится, такой и будет...

Comment: нет, это немного другое ) id тоже играет роль в этом) Почему еще id важно - потому что постом я буду брать первые 2 записи по каждому email-у и отображать их нужным мне образом - но это уже просто сделать)

Comment: Т. е. логика такая у меня, но я не знаю как ее реализовать: 1. Все записи вывести по порядку по date. 2. Сгруппировать записи по emaily. 3. Внутри каждой группы по emaily выбрать уникальные записи. Уникальной записью будет запись, где внутри группы по email-у, не повторяются и carrier и id . 4. вывести 2 самые ранние записи по дате внутри каждой группы по email-у

Comment: Т. е. я не знаю как сделать 3-й пункт с этого процесса.

Comment: Это не совсем корректная логика. В 3-ем пункте предполагается некоторая "уникальность", до сортировки - но такой уникальности не существует. Допустим у нас
`email_1 car_1  2   2019-02-08,   
email_1 car_2   3   2019-02-09,
email_1 car_3   1   2019-02-10`
можно выбрать первую и вторую запись, первую и третью, вторую и третью - каждая пара будет содержать уникальные значения. А если добавить еще `email_1 car_1   1   2019-02-11` - то она вроде не уникальная, но можно считать ее уникальной вместо первой и третьей, которые обе сразу станут не уникальными.

Answer (score 1):

```
with test(email, carrier, id,  date) AS (
    SELECT 'email_1', 'car_1',   1,   '2019-02-08'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'email_1', 'car_1',   1,   '2019-02-09'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'email_1', 'car_1',   2,   '2019-02-10'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'email_1', 'car_2',   2,   '2019-02-11'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'email_2', 'car_3',   3,   '2019-02-09'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'email_2', 'car_4',   4,   '2019-02-09'
), 
data AS (
    SELECT  
        email, carrier, id,  date, 
        row_number() over(partition by email, carrier, id ORDER BY date desc) AS RowNumber -- добавьте сортировку какую вам нужно и партишен такой какой вам нужен чтоб начать отсчет
    FROM test
)
SELECT email, carrier, id,  date FROM data WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT email, carrier, id, MIN(d_date) AS date
FROM test
GROUP BY email, carrier, id
```

[fiddle for MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cba1975f44d6d6f3c39181126184c805)

[fiddle for PostgreSQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0f3d48197cb072e285b485f13393d406)

Comment: к сожалению, это не совсем то, что нужно. Здесь появляется лишняя запись: email_1, car_1, 2. Эта запись лишняя, потому что внутри email_1 же встречается car_1.